# phpspreadsheet error : Message: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am getting error is :

```
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '='

Filename: /volume1/web/dbms/dev/akshay/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Calculation/Calculation.php

Line Number: 2460    

my Code is :

    <?php  
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    class Mgs_to_dbms extends MY_Controller{
       public function transfer_pe(){
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 4):

Which version of PHP are you using, I got the same error today, after switching to PHP 7.2 its gone.

Comment: I was using PHP 7.0.33. But as you said after upgrade Php 7.2 its gone .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Method #1** Update PHP to v7.1

**Method #2** Install a previous version of PhpSpreadsheet

Adjust `composer.json`

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "*"
  }
```

And run

```
php composer.phar update phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```